# IntelliJ IDEA not opening at all due to JavaFX modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a project and I am using JavaFX, installed it and my project worked just fine until I restarted the IDE. Since then it won't open at all, and in Task Manager it pops up for about half a second.

I tried running from cmd the `idea.bat` file. And I get the issue :

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException:
Module javafx.controls not found
```

At first, I also got :

```
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend
bool exclude = true
```

But I managed to delete the line from `idea64.exe.vmoptions` that contained it and it disappeared.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

I am new to JavaFX and I might have messed something up without realising.

Comment: Please try the steps from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559.